# Restore password protected SSD

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, passwords, password-protection

I've got a broken PC which had a LITE-ON LCT-128M3S solid state drive that I would try to throw in my own PC but when I turn on the PC (Even before the opportunity to go into the BIOS ) it asks for a password.

I can do a "hot-plug" on my PC and put the drive in after the pc is started, but Windows does not recognize the disk (I can see it in disc management, but any attempts to change it, provides an I / O error).

I have also tried with an ATA secure erase with parted magic and got the same error = I / O error (Note, it is not frozen according to Perted magic / hdparm)

I'm not interested in the files located on the disk, but i would like to use the drive in my PC. Any of you experts have an idea for what I can do?

Comment: It seems that the drive is capable of self-encryption. Perhaps your hard drive is self-encypted?

Comment: I think it is locked from the Bios, but i'm not sure

Comment: Then it is unlikely you'll get it back, unless you have the password.